# Can I BreakRoleInheritance for root folder in #SharePoint library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, security

Can I BreakRoleInheritance for root folder in SharePoint library. list.RootFolder.Item ruturn null.

Answer (score 2):

You should configure permissions for the library list itself:

```
SPList sharedDocuments = web.Lists.TryGetList("Shared Documents");
sharedDocuments.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
```